# Shuffeled coin tossing

Tags: probability, lebesgue-measure, uniform-distribution

Had a small question: Let's consider the probability space $(\Omega, \mathfrak{F})=([0,1], \mathfrak{B})$ with Lebesgue measure $\mathbb{P}$, $\mathfrak{B}$ is Borel sigma algebra.

Lets expand a point $\omega\in \Omega$ in binary form: $\omega=0.\omega_1\omega_2\omega_3\omega_4\ldots$ and consider a random variable $Y(\omega)$:

$
Y(\omega)=0.\omega_1\omega_3\omega_6\omega_{10}\omega_{15}\ldots
$

i.e. the gap between neighbour indeces increase by 1 with each step. It is asserted that this random variable $Y(\omega)$ is uniformly distributed on $\Omega$. Can't figure out why. Would be highly appreciated for any hint.

Comment: Where did you find this assertion?

Comment: This is asserted in David Williams's book "Probability with martingales" in paragraph 4.6. This is a initial step towards building independent random variables with prescribed distribution function.

Answer (score 0):

This [paper](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-436j-fundamentals-of-probability-fall-2008/lecture-notes/MIT6_436JF08_lec02.pdf) has an explanation about the uniformity of infinite coin tosses.

Also, there is a detailed explanation given in [Santosh Venkatesh's Probability Theory: Explorations and Applications](http://books.google.com/books?id=b8fjfRQAlYAC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false). (starting at p. 144...I linked to the Google preview).

I will not reproduce them here, as these links are excellent.